# updating design and support libs broke UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-cardview

currently we are using design and support libs 23.1.1 , when i updated to 25 there is a big gap in the layout and i can't figure out why

- unfortunately i need more reputation to post links , all the links inside the file , sorry.

https://gist.github.com/xxqxpxx/a652a0c26a132913cd67faf21a670515

included files : build.gradle , layoutfile.xml , fragmentfile.xml , mainactivity ,activity1.

### screenshot before :

[image]

### screenshot after :

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5M5l.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout file change the root Linear layout height form `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/authors_and_publishers_simpleDraweeView_margin_left"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/authors_and_publishers_simpleDraweeView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/author_publishers_simpledraweeview"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/author_publishers_simpledraweeview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/authors_publishers_name_layout_margin_top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.kotobi.widget.fonts.views.textviews.RobotoLight
            android:id="@+id/authorName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_followrs_text_size" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/authors_and_publishers_simpleDraweeView_margin_top">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen_margin_right"
                    android:background="@drawable/followers" />

                <com.kotobi.widget.fonts.views.textviews.RobotoLight
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfFollowers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_followrs_number_books" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_image_dimen_margin_right"
                    android:background="@drawable/number_books" />

                <com.kotobi.widget.fonts.views.textviews.RobotoLight
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfBooks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/author_publisher_pop_up_followrs_number_books" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```